# Dividir valores na moeda brasileira (R$) em php?

Tags: php, number-format

Preciso dividir o valor 6999,99 por 3, mas ao dividir o mesmo retorna 2333,00 ou seja não devolve os centavos, segue um exemplo hipotético:

```
$parcelas = 3;
$valor = double(6.999,99); //já usei com e sem double e na mesma
$valorTotal = number_format($valor, 2, '.', '');
$valor_parcela = $valorTotal / $parcelas;
echo 'R$'. number_format($valor_parcela, 2, ',', '.');
```

O valor já vem formatado do input com uma mascara javascript, se passo o valor desta forma 6999.99, o mesmo é impresso corretamente. Obrigado

Comment: erro está nessa linha `$valor = double(6.999,99);` deveria ser `$valor = 6999.99;`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic já fiz desta forma também mas não funcionou a unica forma que funciona é passando o valor assim 6999.99 se colocar a (virgula) ele dá erro na váriavel Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','.

Comment: transportei para uma resposta, olha lá o exemplo online! funciona como eu disse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa tratar o valor de entrada `6.999,99` para `6999.99`

```
$valor = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', '6.999,99'));
```

Answer (score 4):

O erro está nessa linha `$valor = double(6.999,99);` deveria ser `$valor = 6999.99;`, ou seja, deve ser colocado no lugar do centavos **.** *(ponto)* e no milhar remover a **,** *(virgula)*.

```
<?php    
    $parcelas = 3;
    $valor = 6999.99; 
    $valorTotal = number_format($valor, 2, '.', '');
    $valor_parcela = $valorTotal / $parcelas;
    echo 'R$ '. number_format($valor_parcela, 2, ',', '.');
```

[***Exemplo OnLine***](http://ideone.com/4XgKFx)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php)
- [Números de ponto flutuante](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php)
- [Difference between float and double in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda resolvido usando a dica do str_replace.

Comment: Sim, está a minha resposta talvez faltou essa abordagem do replace, mas, achei que isso você já tinha o conhecimento, porque disso: o php os valores é no formato americano.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso, mas, você entendeu o porque ? resolvido foi, mas, houve algum entendimento?

Comment: Sim agora ficou claro, eu já havia utilizado o replace anteriormente para datas, e não pensei em usa-la achei que houvesse alguma outra função, não pretendo usar framework, ao menos por enquanto, e muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic